# How do I fix LoadIcon() Function not displaying icon?

Tags: c++, object, winapi

I am trying to use a custom icon for my 3D game's application window (see [My first question on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61959571/directx-11-engine-is-not-running-suddenly-after-third-code-improvement-and-i-don) for details on the 3D game) using the `LoadIcon()` function.  I initialized the instance handle like I saw on a code forum site (not anything similar to this one and I'm not even signed up for it) which was to call the `GetModuleHandle()` function and set it's parameter to `NULL`.  Then I used the filenames of the images for both `hIcon` and `hIconSm` which were in the same folder as the executable (I originally had the files in the same folder as the source code but that didn't seem to work). Here's my `WNDCLASSEX` object initialization code (it also has the `HINSTANCE` initialization in it):

```cpp
HINSTANCE hinstance;
hinstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
WNDCLASSEX wc;
wc.cbClsExtra = NULL;
wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.cbWndExtra = NULL;
wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hinstance, "ArtificialIconLg.png");
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hinstance, "ArtificialIcon.ico");
wc.hInstance = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName = "MyWindowClass";
wc.lpszMenuName = "";
wc.style = NULL;
wc.lpfnWndProc = &WndProc;
```

I will also include my `CreateWindowEx()` function:

```cpp
m_hwnd = ::CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, "MyWindowClass", "Artificial", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1024, 768, NULL, NULL, NULL, window);
```

Comment: Try just loading the icons, examining the return value, and checking for errors. If they aren't loading they won't display. The way you have the code right now you don't know.

Comment: Really important that you start checking return values for errors

Comment: Oh, how do I check? I'm kind of new to programming.

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-loadicona) usually explains how the function can fail and what to check.

Comment: Try using `LoadImage(nullptr, "ArtificialIconLg.png", IMAGE_ICON, 0, 0, LR_LOADFROMFILE)`.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I will do that

Comment: *"I promise this question will not be as bad as my last one"* - Incidentally, what question? There is none. Please read [ask].

Comment: @IInspectable I deleted it because it was so bad

Comment: @IInspectable WELL I DIDN'T KNOW THAT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadIcon` only loads art assets from resources compiled into EXEs and DLL.  It takes a resource ID as a second parameter. (The fact that it's typed a string makes it confusing).  Also, I don't think you can load png files directly via LoadIcon.

Add you .ico file to your resource file (.rc file) with your Visual Studio project and add a corresponding identifier in the resources.h file.  Visual Studio does most of this for you if just right click and add.

Then in code:

```
wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hinstance, MAKEINTRESID(ICO_ARTIIFICIAL));
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hinstance, MAKEINTRESID(ICO_ARTIIFICIAL));
```

Comment: How do I add a identifier to the `resources.h` and  `*.rc` files?

Comment: The alternative to loading from a resource is to use the `LoadImage` function. That can load from a file.